GIF image format detection - MAUI
I have a carousel view to display the network image and its move dynamically on every 5 sec ,If the image is gif that should be completely played before moving to next one for that I have to detect if network image is gif or not without using any external package
I need any solution to detect that the network image is gif or not

May I ask what .NET version  and platform you are using? Please also include any relevant code to help us understand the question.
